# Hibernate issue while Migrating JBOSS EAP 6.2 to JBOSS EAP 7.0

Tags: jboss-eap-6, jboss-eap-7

While trying to migrate from JBOSS EAP 6.2 to JBOSS EAP 7.0 facing hibernate issues. I am trying to migrate with existing hibernate 4.x(without using hibenate 5.x) because i'm not supposed do any code change.Please anyone help me out to overcome these issues.

Answer (score 0):

I think the functionality that made Hibernate 4 possible was removed in WildFly / EAP 7.  It was technically possible to integrate some Hibernate 3 releases in EAP 6. The functionality that permitted container integration with Hibernate 4 was removed in the upstream WildFly release on which JBoss EAP 7 is based. The migration integration code that remains in EAP 7 is for Hibernate 4 though this is not tested.

It should be possible, technically, to construct your own entity manager factory or session factory with an arbitrary version of Hibernate by providing appropriate jar files, deployment dependencies, configuration and code. But it would not be fully integrated with the container and this has not been verified.

You should use hibernate5 in EAP7, see below link:

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.0/html-single/migration_guide/#hibernate_and_jpa_migration_changes